# Update data without form using Symfony2

Tags: symfony

I've tried searching about updating data in Symfony2 but look like all tutorials need few normal steps to do this :

1. Manager initialisation `$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();`
2. Make Entity with criteria `$entity =
   $em->getRepository('bundle')->find($id);`
3. Create Form  `$form = $this->createForm(new Type(), $entity);`
4. Bind with request `$editForm->handleRequest($request);`
5. Flush data `$em->flush();`

Let say that I have custom form in twig and do manual getRequest in controller `$variable = $request->request->get('name');`. Is there any way I can do to update this data for specific ID in entity `$entity = $em->getRepository('bundle')->find($id);` without create a form for flush my data?

Because I need to update this variable for many ID in my database using iteration. Let say that I have thousands data need to updated with this value. I'm worried if creating form will impact to performance and time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply set your data directly in your entity using your setters and then flush:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$entity = $em->getRepository('Bundle:Entity')->find($id);

$entity->setSomeProperty($propertyValue);

$em->flush();
```